# setText method not working for javax.swing.JLabel in Java

Tags: java, swing

I made a simple GUI using Swing and everything is just working fine but the JLabel isn't updating when I used the .setText method. I'm really getting confused about the problem as the JLabel should work properly.

```
 // Variables declaration                   
       private javax.swing.JDesktopPane jDesktopPane1;
       private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;     

public NewClass() {
        initComponents();
    }   

     private void initComponents() {
                jDesktopPane1 = new javax.swing.JDesktopPane();
                jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
                jLabel1.setText("Hello JLabel!");
                jDesktopPane1.add(jLabel1, javax.swing.JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);

                javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
                getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
                layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(jDesktopPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 564, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                );
                layout.setVerticalGroup(
                        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(jDesktopPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 388, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                );

                pack();
            }

            public static void main(String args[]) {

                java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        new NewClass().setVisible(true);
                        new NewClass().start();
                    }
                });

            }                

            private void start() {

                this.jLabel1.setText("Hello!");
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new NewClass().setVisible(true);
new NewClass().start();
```

You have created two instances of the NewClass class.

You only want one instance, then you can set the text for the label on the visible frame:

```
NewClass frame = new NewClass();
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.start();
```

If you want to change a property of any Object, then you need a reference to the Object. You can't just keep using the "new" statement.

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly understand what you are trying to do but if you are trying to update the jLabelText at the start of execution try this

```
public NewClass() {
initComponents();
this.setVisible(true);
jLabel1.setText("YourText");
}
```